# How to use field calculator for area calculations in QGis?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate area between contour lines on a DEM with Qgis 1.8.0-Lisboa](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/calculate-area-between-contour-lines-on-a-dem-with-qgis-1-8-0-lisboa)

Based on a DEM of a whole country I have reclassified altitudinal bands with steps of 100 metres (100-200, 200-300...). Then I polygonized the bands in order to get shapefiles and summarized them with the tool „Singleparts to Multiparts“

Now I have one entry in the attribute table for each altitudinal band.

I would like to calculate the area of each band but no matter what I write or select at the field calculator settings, the result is alwasy the same (Even if I change the CRS). And when I save it (finishing the edit mode) the number turns to 0. What am I doing wrong?

I am using qgis 1.8.0.

Comment: What value returns typing $area in the raster calculator ?

Comment: For the new field / column being calculated, what type is it? Integer, Double Precision, String?

Comment: The value in the attribut table is integer. The area I would like to calculate in real. I always get numbers like 0.0484618034274718 no matter if I change the CRS for the project or the layer. I dont know what type this is cause I always get the same and cannot compare anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the function list on the left hand side of the field calculator, click the plus sign on the Geometry function.  In the expanded list of geometry functions, select $area.