# How to calculate the area between two contour line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

I created contours by using SRTM30 data. Now I need to find area between two contours like in between 0 m to 50 m depth and 50 m to 100 m.

Comment: Do you need the 2D area or 3D area?

Comment: You can only caclulate the area of polygons

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate te area between contour lines on a DEM with Qgis 1.8?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/how-to-calculate-te-area-between-contour-lines-on-a-dem-with-qgis-1-8) - While different software, it is the principles of the area calculation which are relevant.

Comment: @MappaGnosis, the question you mentioned is addressed to QGIS tools, and this question is addressed to ArcGIS.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I agree - the QGIS question will help but is not a duplicate - mind you I think it would have helped attract potential answerers if the asker had included a picture to illustrate.

Comment: You have an [tag:arcgis-desktop] but do not mention having tried to use that software in your question.  I recommend providing just a few details of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Would you like to compute the area defined by each two contours, or the total area for each interval - i.e. area between a certain 50 meters and a certain 40 meters contours, or the area between ALL 50 and 40 meters contours.

Comment: esri (I think Steve Lynch) has a pyt toolset SA Supplemental tools. Here:http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/01/new-spatial-analyst-supplemental-tools-v1-2-august-2013/

Comment: Another related question (since you have to have something to color it, and if you have it you can measure the area of it): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61550/colouring-areas-between-vector-contours Of course the 2D/3D area issue still stands.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen Spatial Analyst Supplemental tools :
Here :
[SA Supplemental tools](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/01/new-spatial-analyst-supplemental-tools-v1-2-august-2013/) or a [direct download page](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3528bd72847c439f88190a137a1d0e67).

You might also want to refer to the [create Field Contours page](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/21/create-filled-contours-script-tool-for-arcgis-10/) in which you will find a comment about script modifications to allowed for customized contour intervals.

One of these builds a "filled polygon contour" from a raster dem. Not exactly what you are looking for but may be useful.

Comment: Actually - This is exactly what he was looking for:  "...filled contour polygons can be used to easily find the area of elevation values between two particular elevation contours"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vector-based suggested workflow to compute the area for **each** contour interval in your data set. You might want to look for some "easier" to implement solutions in other sources - here is [one](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/80851).

As to the suggested work flow:

1. Start with converting your contours to polygons (Feature to Polygon [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000)) and add a field named: "Within" of an integer type.
   This next phase should be based on a model or a python script. It is rather simple, thus model would do the job. Build a model that will
2. [Iterate rows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000010000000.htm) in your new polygon layer
3. for each row - create a temporary layer using [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000); use the Get Field Value [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000006000000.htm) to extract the contour value of the temporary layer into a model variable.
4. Use select layer by location [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000) to select from your polygons layer the features that are WITHIN_CLEMENTINI your temporary layer.
5. Use select by attributes [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Attribute/001700000071000000/) and define REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION as your selection_type. Use an expression that will unselect (remove) all selected features that ther contour value distance from your row contour value is bigger than the contours interval. For example:
   Let's say that you have contours every 15 meters. Than you should write an expression that will select all [Temporary_Contour_Value]-[Contour]>15
6. Now you have the contour the "biggest"/"highest" contour within your row. Use get Field value again to extract the selection ID, you might need to write it as temporary layer. Than write the extracted ID value to the within field in your iterated row. You might consider to use the [Calculate field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tool.
7. Last phase of each loop is to CLEAR_SELECTION using Select layer by attributes.

Now after the model have run you have, for each row, a field which tells you which contour polygon is within it (by ID). All you have to do is compute shape are (you can use the python expression !shape.area! in the field calculator - it is a double/float type). 
Make a copy of this layer and join it to itself when the PK is your within field and the FK is your original ID. 
Use field calculator again to compute the area within two contours, bu expression Area_1 (of origianl layer) - Area_2 (of the joint layer).

You can also incorparate all steps into one model. It is just a workflow, since I havn't tried it since I don't have arcmap on my computer. Some difficulties might come up with the "get field value" variables - so you might want to use .py after all (with the same workflow).