# Area elevation distribution with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster DEM and a polygon covering a part of it. I need an area-elevation distribution (i.e. how many m2 are in which elevation interval). 20m intervals will be fine.
I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you describe the distribution that you're after? For example, is the x-axis the area (as % of basin or polygon) and the y-axis is elevation less than or equal to?

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- Generate contours at the desired intervals from your DEM and use the lines to cut up your polygon.
- Clip your DEM using your polygon, then reclassify the DEM using the
  desired interval ranges, followed by a little math - get the number
  of pixels in each class times the area of a pixel. (See [Measuring area of raster classes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106883/measuring-area-of-raster-classes/) which discusses ArcGIS tools, but the methods would be the same.)

Some related questions:

- [How to calculate te area between contour lines on a DEM with QGIS 1.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44208/)
- [How to calculate the area between two contour line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122106/)