# Calculating area from DEM value range in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, area

Is it possible to calculate the area of a DEM in specific value ranges, e.g. the total area between 200 and 300 meters of elevation?

Using QGIS and my DEM is 1m. Would like to do this for my DEM, so that in a second step I can visualise the number of features in each value range.

[image]

Comment: Using the raster calculator create a mask where every area between 200 and 300 m is taken into account, then convert to contour lines, then to polygons, then calculate area.

Comment: You can try "Raster layer histogram", then multiply by pixel size

Answer (score 1):

1. Create contour polygons using [`Menu Processing / Toolbox / Contour polygons`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html?highlight=contour%20polygon#contour-polygons).

   *It's a GDAL tool (requires GDAL ver. 2.4.0. or later), available in QGIS. If you find only [contour](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html?highlight=contour%20polygon#contour), set there the flag `-p`, see GDAL documentation: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html*
2. Select the relevant polygons and calculate the area with field calculator.

*DEM with a contour polygon for the range between 200 and 300 m:*
[image]